# Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде

Tags: java, if, while

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде. Если задаю начальные координаты (0;0) и двигаю робота в точку (-1;-1), то код не проходит тест, то есть робот не приходит в заданную точку.

Описание: На игровом поле находится робот. Позиция робота на поле описывается двумя целочисленным координатами: X и Y. Ось X смотрит слева направо, ось Y — снизу вверх.

В начальный момент робот находится в некоторой позиции на поле. Также известно, куда робот смотрит: вверх, вниз, направо или налево. Direction, направление взгляда робота,  — это перечисление:
public enum Direction {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
задача — привести робота в заданную точку игрового поля. Как это выглядит: см картинка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прилагаю код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot robot = new Robot(0, 0, Direction.UP); 
        moveRobot(robot, -1, -1);   
    }

    public enum Direction {
        UP,
        DOWN,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT
    }

    public static class Robot {
        int X; 
        int Y; 
        Direction dir;

        public Robot(int X, int Y, Direction dir) {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
            this.dir = dir;
        }

        public Direction getDirection() {
            // текущее направление взгляда
            return dir;
        }

        public int getX() {
            // текущая координата X
            return X;
        }

        public int getY() {
            // текущая координата Y
            return Y;
        }

        public void turnLeft() {
            // повернуться на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки
            if (dir == Direction.UP) {
                dir = Direction.LEFT;
            } else if (dir == Direction.DOWN) {
                dir = Direction.RIGHT;
            } else if (dir == Direction.LEFT) {
                dir = Direction.DOWN;
            } else if (dir == Direction.RIGHT) {
                dir = Direction.UP;
            }
        }

        public void turnRight() {
            // повернуться на 90 градусов по часовой стрелке
            if (dir == Direction.UP) {
                dir = Direction.RIGHT;
            } else if (dir == Direction.DOWN) {
                dir = Direction.LEFT;
            } else if (dir == Direction.LEFT) {
                dir = Direction.UP;
            } else if (dir == Direction.RIGHT) {
                dir = Direction.DOWN;
            }
        }

        public void stepForward() {
            // шаг в направлении взгляда
            // за один шаг робот изменяет одну свою координату на единицу
            if (dir == Direction.UP) {
                Y++;
            }
            if (dir == Direction.DOWN) {
                Y--;
            }
            if (dir == Direction.LEFT) {
                X--;
            }
            if (dir == Direction.RIGHT) {
                X++;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void moveRobot(Robot robot, int toX, int toY) { 

        int dirX = robot.getX();
        int dirY = robot.getY();

       System.out.println("Начальная позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());

        if (dirY >= toY) {
            while (robot.getDirection() != Direction.DOWN) {
                robot.turnLeft();
            }
            while (dirY != toY) {
                robot.stepForward();
               System.out.println("dirY >= toY " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
                dirY--;
            }

        } else {
            while (robot.getDirection() != Direction.UP) {
                robot.turnRight();
            }
            while (dirY != toY) {
                robot.stepForward();
                System.out.println("dirY <= toY " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
                dirY++;
            }
        }
            if (dirX >= toX) {
                while (robot.getDirection() != Direction.LEFT) {
                    robot.turnLeft();
                }
                while (dirX != toX) {
                    robot.stepForward();
                    System.out.println("dirX >= toX " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
                    dirX--;
                }
            } else {
                while (robot.getDirection() != Direction.RIGHT) {
                    robot.turnRight();
                }
                while (dirX != toX) {
                    robot.stepForward();
                    System.out.println("dirX <= toX " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
                    dirX++;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

P.S. Буду признательна если поможете улучшить/ сократить данный код, я пока учусь и буду рада ценному совету. Заранее спасибо! Хорошей недели :)

Comment: "код не проходит тест", может быть, точку куда нужно передвинуться надо считывать, а не самому хардкодить?

Comment: мне посоветовали в тесте задать начальные координаты (0;0) и конечные координаты робота  (-1;-1), с другими координатами у меня все нормально работало

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сократить код метода moveRobot? пока только учусь, буду рада ценному совету :) Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Робот приходит в точку `(-1, -1)`. Может, есть еще условие, куда он должен в результате смотреть? Например, туда же, куда смотрел сначала.

```
    public void stepForward() {
        // шаг в направлении взгляда
        // за один шаг робот изменяет одну свою координату на единицу
        switch(dir) {
          case Direction.UP   : Y++; break;
          case Direction.DOWN : Y--; break;
          case Direction.LEFT : X--; break;
          case Direction.RIGHT: X++; break;
        }
    }
```

---

> как можно сократить код метода moveRobot?

```
public static void moveRobot(Robot robot, int toX, int toY) { 
  System.out.println("Начальная позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());

  if (robot.getY() != toY) {
    while (robot.getDirection() != (robot.getY() < toY)? Direction.UP :  Direction.DOWN) {
      robot.turnLeft();
    }
    while (robot.getY() != toY) {
      robot.stepForward();
    }
  }
  if (robot.getX() != toX) {
    while (robot.getDirection() != (robot.getX() < toX)? Direction.RIGHT :  Direction.LEFT) {
      robot.turnLeft();
    }
    while (robot.getX() != toX) {
      robot.stepForward();
    }
  }

  System.out.println("Ending позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
}
```

Comment: нет, такого не было в описании задачи. Я так понимаю, что он должен смотреть в направлении своего движения

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сократить код метода moveRobot? пока только учусь, буду рада ценному совету :) Заранее спасибо

Comment: Igor, большое спасибо за помощь! Хорошей недели :)

Comment: @user4166 Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: Igor и stackoverflow сообщество, подскажите, пожалуйста, а если например, направлений взгляда робота будет не 4 (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT), а 20, как лучше реализовать метод moveRobot? заранее спасибо!