# Как оптимизировать метод moveRobot

Tags: java, циклы, while

Возвращаюсь к предыдущей задаче, рассмотренной здесь [Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089153/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5/1089156?noredirect=1#comment1874764_1089156)

Мне очень понравилось решение по сокращению кода moveRobot, но оно не учитывает условие, при котором направлений взгляда робота не 4 (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT), а например 20... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае реализовать метод moveRobot. Заранее спасибо!

```
public static void moveRobot(Robot robot, int toX, int toY) { 
  System.out.println("Начальная позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());

  if (robot.getY() != toY) {
    while (robot.getDirection() != ((robot.getY() < toY)? Direction.UP :  Direction.DOWN)) {
      robot.turnLeft();
    }
    while (robot.getY() != toY) {
      robot.stepForward();
    }
  }
  if (robot.getX() != toX) {
    while (robot.getDirection() != ((robot.getX() < toX)? Direction.RIGHT :  Direction.LEFT)) {
      robot.turnLeft();
    }
    while (robot.getX() != toX) {
      robot.stepForward();
    }
  }

  System.out.println("Ending позиция " + robot.getX() + " " + robot.getY() + ". Направление взгляда: " + robot.getDirection());
}
```

Comment: @Igor, добрый день! Сможете помочь с данным вопросом? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добрый день, есть знатоки?